# How do I add ListFormWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I see this web part in the default display form for a list only. How can I add it to another page? I checked all of the categories and list form is not an option. The goal is the use this instead of the dataview web part that is created with SharePoint designer 2013 by default, I do not see this web part in there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods for your requirement:

1. Use Page Viewer web part. Add “IsDlg=1” behind the display form URL and type in the web page link in the Page Viewer web part edit panel.

[image]

2. Use SharePoint Designer 2013. Edit the page in Advanced mode->INSERT tab->Display Item Form->select the relevant list->Save.

[image]